# Hosting Visual Studio projects in dropbox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-8, dropbox

I develop both on my desktop and laptop, and I am frequently switching between them. Are there any problems that could arise from keeping a project folder in my dropbox and always accessing/editing from there? I'm running the VS2010 on both, but W7 on one and W8 on the other.

Comment: have you considered using a proper Source Control solution, such as the free Team Foundation Services? http://tfs.visualstudio.com/

Comment: I done that once and after a while my DP stooped sync. I don'T know why, but you should definitely give tfs or github a try.

Comment: @jessehouwing I actually like the idea of using a cloud better when it's only a few people (and especially when it's a one-person project). It's just simple access with no weird terminology and stuff to learn (like committing, pulling, approving, and all the messy stuff).

Answer (score 3):

I'm using it often. But I do experience some issues. It seems that sometime VS and Dropbox conflict. This shows by leaving some temporary source files or by errors during compilation of file being locked.

In fact I came here while looking how to solve them. But still they are only a little issue and I keep using it that way for a long time.

EDIT: It is not just me. See [Visual studio 2012 and dropbox don't play nice together](https://superuser.com/questions/485041/visual-studio-2012-and-dropbox-dont-play-nice-together) question on SuperUser.

Comment: You might see [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21855956/673991):  fatal error C1041: cannot open program database '....pdb'; if multiple CL.EXE write to the same .PDB file

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Dropbox to host my project and I edit and build directly on there and have experienced no problems, ever. Win7, VS2010, CPP. I find Dropbox to be simpler and equally robust to than version control software. I'm a big fan. I should say Microsoft OneDrive once failed me, horribly, and I no longer trust it. With Dropbox, I always check the icon in the systray carefully to make sure it is finished updating before I turn my computer off.

Answer (score 0):

I use both git and Dropbox, as I also switch which machine I'm working on.  This way I can use source control with the rest of my team, while also able to pick up where I left off.  My 2 PCs that sync are my one at work and at home.  Both desktops, both almost always on and running dropbox.
Rarely I get conflicts, when a machine is offline or something.  The solution 99% of the time is to simply delete any conflicting files.  Because I'm constantly up to date with git, it's fine if I ever have to delete all my local code, since I can always get it back.
So it's really for nothing other than being able to run out of work on an urgent task, and then resume where I left off when I got home.