# Visual Studio 2013 fatal error C1041 /FS

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013. Every so often by project refuses to compile. If I undo any changes, it still won't compile. I've found that recreating the entire project works. I would like to actually fix the problem though. The error that I'm getting is:

```
1>Critic.cpp : fatal error C1041: cannot open program database 'c:\users\username\desktop\projectName\projectName\x64\debug\vc120.pdb'; if multiple CL.EXE write to the same .PDB file, please use /FS
```

I've tried following these instructions to no avail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn502518.aspx

Has anyone else encountered this and found a fix?

Comment: Typing that up gave me an idea. I disabled Carbonite (an online backup service) in case it was interfering and then restarted and my project compiled. If you're having this problem and you find this, you might want to disable anything that might be locking files on your machine.

Comment: Did you try the /FS recommended by the error message?

Comment: @cup Yes, the /FS flag did not fix it.

Comment: Delete the *.pdb files and rebuild.

Comment: This used to happen on VS10, especially on multicore machines that cache stuff.  Try setting %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS% to 1 on a cmd prompt and launching VS from there.  Then build.

Comment: I use Perforce and if a pdb file is accidentally checked in but not checked back out then an error like this can happen. Perhaps Carbonite is accidentally backing up the pdb file and not giving you access back? Source control is typically my first suspect with issues like this.

Comment: Try toggling the Solution Configuration. e.g. **Release** to **Debug** and back to **Release**

Comment: This also happens when you're debugging multiple projects that use the same shared library that tries to compile.

Answer (score 74):

I had this problem because different projects in a solution had the same intermediate directory.

Changing

```
$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\
```

to

```
$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\$(ProjectName)\
```

in

**Configuration Properties** | **General** | **Intermediate Directory**

in each of the projects solved it.

Comment: Using `/FS` worked for me until my SLN grew even larger; then I needed this.

Comment: According to the M$ documentation itself:
"this may make builds significantly longer, and it doesn't prevent all errors that may occur when multiple instances of cl.exe access the PDB file at the same time. We recommend that you change your solution so that independent projects write to separate intermediate and output locations"

So I believe this is the correct answer - don't reuse the same pdb for multiple projects - it will not work reliably.

Comment: For those needing to substantiate this change, here's the link to the documentation that @jj99 is referring to: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/cpp/build/reference/fs-force-synchronous-pdb-writes?view=msvc-160

Answer (score 12):

I agree with **PThomasCS**.

Firstly I tried to use Microsoft advice [/FS (Force Synchronous PDB Writes)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn502518.aspx):

To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development environment

1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see Working with Project Properties.
2. Select the C/C++ folder.
3. Select the Command Line property page.
4. Modify the Additional Options property to include /FS and then choose OK.

but it didn't work.

I noticed that dropbox lock the file. I stopped the synchronization. After that error disappeared. So try to close/stop any program that may lock the files.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

if you use CUDA, then set

Project -> Properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Host -> Additional Compiler Options -> /FS

Answer (score 8):

in the **C/C++->General** settings page for each project, setting the **Multi_processor compilation** option to **No** helped me.

Comment: Yeah, but it would hurt the compile time :)

Answer (score 7):

I found the same problem compiling [libkml](http://code.google.com/p/libkml/) on VS2013 (the error appears specifically at *libkmlxsd* project inside *libkml* solution).

```
Error   112 error C1041: cannot open program database 'd:\gstabel\falkermap2\libkml-1.2.0\msvc\debug\vc120.pdb'; if multiple CL.EXE write to the same .PDB file, please use /FS d:\gstabel\falkermap2\libkml-1.2.0\src\stdafx.cpp   1   1   libkmlxsd
```

The [/FS (Force Synchronous PDB Writes)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn502518.aspx) flag work for me. But I had to set in **all projects** inside the solutions, and Rebuild all, to make it works.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem:  c++ repos that would build fine for other people on my team would not build properly for me (gave .PDB /FS errors as mentioned in the question) and sometimes also link errors.  Someone pointed out that I was cloning one of the repos to a location in my Dropbox.  After trying many other ideas, I finally made a new clone to a non-dropbox location and the solution compiles without errors.  I suspect that the issue could be common to other file synchronization services. (Box, Google drive etc), though I have not tested those.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with vs2017 generated with cmake. I tried adding `/FS` to both `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` but it didn't help. I did not want to sacrifice multi-processor compilation because I have a fairly large project and I want my project built as fast as possible using all the cores available on my PC.

So instead, I opted to switch cmake's default debug flag `/Zi` to `/Z7` which embeds the debug symbols into the `.obj` (similar to how GCC/Clang works) instead of creating an external `.pdb`. It worked for me.

```
    STRING(REGEX REPLACE "/Zi" "/Z7" CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
    STRING(REGEX REPLACE "/Zi" "/Z7" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
```

Please be aware that using `/Z7` will make your binary significantly larger.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too and I solved it by deleting .pdb file from project directory and recompiling

Answer (score 4):

As the error message hints, this error happens when multiple processes try to access the project's PDB file at the same time, which can happen if you enable parallel compilation (I had the problem with a third-party build scheduler, I'm not sure whether this can happen also when the build is managed by Visual Studio's own scheduler).

The instructions to use the /FS compiler option point you in the right direction, the trick is making sure that the compiler option is always used in your compilation.

**If you're using [CMake](https://cmake.org/) to generate the solution file**, you should specify the /FS flag in the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and/or `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` (to see them you might need to tick the *Advanced* checkbox in the CMake GUI) and regenerate the solution.

**If you're using CUDA**, as [Fillippo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3933809/fillippo) noted in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34466505/3214872), you need to make sure the host compiler sets the flag as well. For a Visual Studio-generated solution, set the flag in the CUDA C/C++ -> Host -> Additional Compiler Options in the project properties page.
For CMake-generated solution files, however, you won't have any CUDA C++ properties page, so you need to edit the CMake configuration instead.
Just add the /FS flag to the `CMAKE_{C,CXX}_FLAGS` as mentioned above and check that `CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS` is set to ON ([which is its default value](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindCUDA.html)).

Answer (score 3):

I was running a backup service. My problem was that the backup service kept backing up the new .pdb file from the previous compilation when the compiler tried to write out the .pdb file. By excluding .pdb files from backup I resolved this issue for good.

This type of problem is hard to track down because it is intermittent. After the backup is completed there is no longer a conflict when the compiler creates the new .pdb file, so you may think some other solutions worked.

Answer (score 2):

same problem here too

- /FS did not work
- deleting VS2013 files did not work
- restarting the computer did not work
- removing the header and source files from the project and re-adding them, did not work
- turning off google drive and dropbox did not work

I had to delete the corrupted copy and use my backup copy - usually everyday, I drop a copy of my working folder into a backup drive

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple projects within the solution, you need to add /FS to each project for it to work. Simply select the project->properties->C/C++ -> Commandline ->Additional Options.

Answer (score 2):

What solved it for me was to manually kill the mspdbsrv process.   Something in there occasionally doesn't handle concurrent builds well, and gets stuck in an erroneous state.
The next build re-launched the pdb server and all went back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

The /FS tag need to be place in linker command Line. Work well

Comment: FS = Force Synchronous, what, why, how... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn502518.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Delete the whole debug directory.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the solution was very simple: the disk was full...

But the error message was not very helpful in this case...
I found it by using process monitor.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the Intermediate directory was empty for that project. So the accepted fix did not work for me.

I fixed it by doing a clean and build on the project that gave the error

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue while building in Qt Creator with MSVC. Creating the missing `debug` folder and rebuilding fixed the issue.

Comment: If using qmake, add this to your .pro file:
`QMAKE_CFLAGS+=/FS`

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to build on a docker volume. It seems that cl.exe cannot handle mapped directories. I copied the files to a non-mapped folder and it compiled successfully.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons why this error may occur is that pdb files are marked with a read-only attribute. If they are, remove the read-only attribute from the file.

To remove 
Right Clik on PDB File -> Properties -> Uncheck Attributes: ReadOnly

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on several projects. On those projects I had `<ProgramDataBaseFileName>` set under the `<ClCompile>` section. Removing the `<ProgramDataBaseFileName>` section and its tag (so that Visual Studio uses the default) made this go away.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I couldn't even delete the pdb files of my project. Windows told me that the application `serviceHub.Host.CLR.x64` accessed these files. This process is used by Visual Studio although Visual Studio was restarted.
Killing this process helped!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by Sign out & Log In

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

Deleting complete $(IntDir) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2019 => Tools => Options => Projects and Solutions => Build and Run => Set The Maximum number of parallel project builds to 1

[Improved Parallelism](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/improved-parallelism-in-msbuild/)