# Qt 5.2 with msvc2012 error while building a project

Tags: c++, qt, build, compilation, cl.exe

Operating system is Windows 7 64 bit
I installed Qt with MSVC 2012, then I installed Visual Studio 2012.
Everything fine.. but when I try to build my project, it says

Translated from German to English:

```
Program database "d:\something\mym.pdb" could not be opened, use /FS if multiple CL.EXE write in the same .PDB File
```

Please help!

Comment: What Qt version do you have? Starting from some version they started to add `/FS` forcefully to MSVC2012+ specs. You may add it as compiler flag in your project though.

Comment: The latest: 5.2
so I cannot understand, why this problem happens

Comment: hmm looks like they added `/FS` to spec only for MSVC 2013 so it shouldn't be required for 2012. I use 2012 myself and haven't encountered problems like that, so that's all pretty strange. Try adding `/FS` to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` though.

Comment: hmm.. very strange. I added /FS to the .pro file like this
`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /FS`
It still doesn't work. Did I do it right?

Comment: Well you sure run `qmake -tp vc` after that?  Well for me there's no such option in project settings of VS2012 so as I said it's pretty strange that it asks for it, I'm confused)

Comment: I use QtCreator and the build settings look like this:
`qmake.exe MyM.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2012 "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=declarative_debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"`

Comment: sadly I have no experience with using QtCreator and msvc compiler so you better wait for someone else to answer, though it's nevertheless very strange that `cl.exe` asks for option which shouldn't be implemented at the moment of VS2012. Maybe you're using VS2013 compiler but trying to build with VS2012 spec?

Comment: Predelnik is right in his last comment: I got the same error, resolved by installing Visual Studio 2012

Comment: I am getting this error using Qt 5.7 and VS2015. Adding `/FS` to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` makes it possible to build if I trigger the build three times in a row, so even with that something is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2013 fatal error C1041 /FS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643370/visual-studio-2013-fatal-error-c1041-fs)