# cpp:-1: error: C1041: cannot open program database; untitled-build-desktop-debug\vc120.pdb'

Tags: c++, qt

All the answers available for this problem are solutions for Visual studio. I am facing this problem in QT. I run a sample example but this error pops up.Could somebody help.

error: C1041: cannot open program database 'c:\users\newfolder\untitled-build-desktop-debug\vc120.pdb'; if multiple CL.EXE write to the same .PDB file, please use /FS

Comment: terminate all the cl.exe and qt processes, delete the pdb file, and restart qt.

Comment: Surely that's a compiler error - you say you get this when you try to run something?

Comment: yes, i just added a push button and label. On click, change the label. but it shows this error. I tried to remove the .pdb file but it recreates it when i build the program.

I get the following error now.

:-1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'c:\Qt\4.8.5\lib\qtmaind.lib'

Comment: How do you build?  (QT is not a compiler)

Comment: i build it using a MinGW compiler

Comment: Maybe your should take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643370/visual-studio-2013-fatal-error-c1041-fs).

Answer (score 0):

right click on project-> properties->c/c++ -> output files:
in Program Database File Name: include the project name with path. (.../../../../release/ProjectName/)

This approaches works for me.

Comment: That seem to be in Visual Studio, this question was specifically not about Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer may or may not only apply to those who have built QT from source.)

Ensure you are building with the same Visual Studio toolchain version that your QT distribution was built for.

I got this error when I used a build kit (Options -> Build & Run -> Kits) that was configured to use MSVC 2013 (12.0), but the QT Version was `msvc2010_opengl`. Apparently the discrepancy led to an invalid build configuration. Modifying the build kit to use VS 2010 fixed the problem.