# PDB synchronous write errors even with /FS

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, ninja

I have a simple CMakeLists to compile detours express

```
project(detours)
add_library(detours STATIC detours.cpp disasm.cpp image.cpp modules.cpp creatwth.cpp)
file(COPY detours.h detver.h DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include)
```

The necessary flags are set in an upper level CMakeLists

```
add_definitions(-DDETOURS_X86 -DDETOURS_32BIT)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /FS")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /FS")
```

Yet when trying to compile a debug build each .cpp file after `detours.cpp` throws

> FAILED: C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1.0\VC\bin\cl.exe /nologo /TP -DDETOURS_32BIT -DDETOURS_X86 -Iinclude /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /FS /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 /showIncludes /Foext\detours_express_3.0\src\CMakeFiles\detours.dir\modules.cpp.obj \Fdext\detours_express_3.0\src\CMakeFiles\detours.dir\ /FS -c ..\ext\detours_express_3.0\src\modules.cpp
>   ..\ext\detours_express_3.0\src\modules.cpp : fatal error C1041: cannot open program database 'z:\repo\src\ext\detours_express_3.0\src\cmakefiles\detours.dir\vc120.pdb'; if multiple CL.EXE write to the same .PDB file, please use /FS

If I re-run `ninja detours` then the same happens with the next 3 cpp files, then the next 2, then the last, then the project is fully compiled.

If I run `ninja -j1 detours` then there are no issues, since I just disabled parrallel builds.

Why does it seem to be ignoring my /FS option?
I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

**Update 1**

This is inside a VM in Virtualbox 4.3.10 with Guest Additions. Z:\ is a shared folder that I mounted.
I've made sure to disable Windows Defender in the VM and the host, and uninstalled the third-party AV on the host.

**Update 2**

I found a workaround that avoids the symptoms and added it as an answer, but it still doesn't explain why `/FS` isn't actually synchronizing the locks.

Comment: Looks like CMake is unrelated here, as it adds `/FS` flag automatically (just before `-c`). Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643370/visual-studio-2013-fatal-error-c1041-fs. Probably, some external process locks your `.pdb` file. What kind of drive is `Z:/`?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the /FS but figured I'd add it as a sanity check. I've poked through those solutions. It looks like each project already has an intermediate dir of it's own, `detours.dir` for example, and in this case I'm only compiling one project. It looks like the .cpp files are fighting over the .pdb, which would make sense since they'll all belong to the same executable later. I've tried searching for handles with ProcessExplorer while compiling but haven't had luck yet.

Answer (score 2):

Not so much a solution as a workaround. It appears that whatever mechanism VirtualBox uses to implement shared folders is the culprit. I replaced the virtual box shared folder with a windows shared folder and I am no longer getting these errors.

It's strange that sequential builds don't cause these errors, perhaps compiling the first file causes a sync that prevents the other files from locking until it's done, and since the build is parallel the other .cpp files run into the lock. I'm not sure if this is VirtualBox's or MSVC's fault, though, since this seems like the kind of problem that `/FS` is supposed to fix.

**Steps**

1. Disconnect network map from within VM
2. Remove shared folder from VirtualBox settings
3. Setup a Windows Share on host (Right click folder -> Share)
4. Map this share in the VM

Comment: It is non unusual that building on non-local drives can cause unexected errors. Probably, Virtual Box share folders just doesn's supports file locking, or support it in a very simplified way. It is not a problem of MSVC and `/FS` option implementation. It is just a limitation of Virtual Box share, which unlikely will be fixed in the near future.

Comment: Interesting.  We are building on a Horzon client VM with a Windows Share.  It seems that there is a latency with the share that causes /MP (multiprocess builds) to fail intermittantly.  We find the same solution builds reliably on a desktop system with local drives.
It's odd that the documentation states that /MP automatically invokes /FS.
The suggestion to set /Z7 instead of /Zi to embed the debug symbols in the .obj instead of creating a *.pdb file is a good temporary work around.  Still digging.