# Visual studio build error (please use /fs)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I program C++ in visual studio 2013. recently there may have been a problem. it doesn't show underlined syntax error while coding and i see the **(cannot open program database if multiple cl.exe write to the same .Pdb file please use /fs)** almost every time I compile. however when i open the code in a new file, it compiles.
its really irritating, I hope someone can help?

Comment: Did you try to use /fs as the error clearly stated? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fs-force-synchronous-pdb-writes?view=msvc-170

Comment: yes I did, yet the compilation crashes every third or fourth time.

Comment: it's because the project is configured to be building in parallel. If you create a new project then it's not parallel by default so it should pass. But why do you use a 9-year-old compiler nowadays?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the situation encountered in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643370/visual-studio-2013-fatal-error-c1041-fs) is similar to yours, I suggest you refer to the method mentioned in the link.

> Changing
>
> $(Platform)$(Configuration)\ to
>
> $(Platform)$(Configuration)$(ProjectName)\ in
>
> Configuration Properties | General | Intermediate Directory